# How to get max_allocated_packets from JDBC connection from a Slick DB connection to MySQL

Tags: mysql, scala, jdbc, slick

Is there a way via Scala with Slick database query and access library (or using other tricks - dare I say mocks?) to get `max_allocated_packets` from JDBC-read connection properties from a Slick-style DB connection to MySQL?

As I suspect, the code makes several touch type actions at deeper levels and this connection property is then populated.

Ex: Once a connection is made in `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl` ... using Scala with the Slick library... the value for the JDBC connect property of `max_allocated_packets` is within the object (debugged in IntelliJ). How can I extract this value or obtain it in higher level code as asked above?

Of course I can query the DB directly to get that value, but I am hoping I can extract this property after the setup phase.

Answer (score 0):

If the value is publically available on a connection, you could try to use `SimpleDBIO` action to access the JDBC-level values.

See: https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.2.0/dbio.html#jdbc-interoperability

It would be of the form:

```
val getMaxPacketAction = SimpleDBIO[Int] { database => 
  // make use of database.connection here 
}
```

However, this is still going to the database for a connection, so it may be just easier to query for the value you want.

Comment: Yeah ... I am trying to avoid making a call to the DB.